# Avoid having to map hundreds or thousands of hostnames to an Azure Web Site

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a need to have hundreds or even thousands of hostnames point at a single Azure Web Site.  For a simple rationale, you could think of this as a vanity/branding redirection site.  For example:

1. Visiting http://marketing.example.com would get you redirected to say https://example.sharepoint.com/sites/themarketingteam
2. Visiting http://finance.example.com would get you redirected to say http://someinternalservce.example.com/reports/finance
3. Visiting http://hr.example.com/ would get you redirected to say https://saponline.net/examplecorp

---

I know I can have a *.example.com DNS entry mapped to my azure web application but that isn't attractive because the domain only gets one of those and trying to convince the powers to be that this relatively simple/silly needs is how they use the wild card entry.

Likewise, I know I can go into the Azure portal and/or use Powershell to manually add entries to the configuration but that seems like a lot of extra work and requires the people managing the redirect mappings to have a lot more control over the Azure settings for the web application.

---

Is there any clever workarounds to this solution? Is there a tier of service that gets my app my own IP address that lets me do DNS aliases for? Is there some other Azure offering that might do url rewriting/forwarding to my app that doesn't have the above limitations?

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, you could leverage [IIS URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) and [Using rewrite maps for redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-rewrite-maps-in-url-rewrite-module) for configuring the following code into the `system.webServer` section of web.config file for your website as follows:

```html
<rewrite>
  <rewriteMaps>
    <rewriteMap name="hostRedirects">
      <add key="marketing.example.com" value="https://example.sharepoint.com/sites/themarketingteam"/>
      <add key="finance.example.com" value="http://someinternalservce.example.com/reports/finance"/>
    </rewriteMap>
  </rewriteMaps>

  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect rule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*"/>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{hostRedirects:{HTTP_HOST}}" pattern="(.+)"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Also, you could use DbProvider, FileMapProvider, etc for storing the URL mappings into the db or file. I would recommend you using the FileMapProvider which could store the rewrite map entries in a single file instead of keeping them in a web.config file. For more details, you could refer to [Using Custom Rewrite Providers with URL Rewrite Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-custom-rewrite-providers-with-url-rewrite-module).

Additionally, you could write your code and build a custom HttpMoudle to check the incoming host, then redirect as you wish. Here is a blog talking about the detailed steps, you could refer to [here](http://alexwolfthoughts.com/efficient-mvc-redirects-using-an-http-module/).

Comment: The problem I see with this is to run the rewrite rule in an IIS application means that in an azure web site, I have to do all the domain mapping in the portal OR if I do this in an IaaS Windows VM then I have to spend the hassle of keeping that box patched and up to date, etc.

Comment: I have noticed that AWS' elasticbeanstalk service allows you to assign a dedicated IP address to the web applications that you deploy with them.